# Center columns Materialize

Tags: materialize

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="login-page" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4 z-depth-6 card-panel teal">
        <h1>Hi</h1><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a l4 and m6 centered column. s12 does it pretty well, but l4 always stay at the left on big screens. How can I center this columns?

Answer (score 9):

Try adding classes `offset-m3` and `offset-l4` to your div:

```
<div id="login-page" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3 l4 offset-l4 z-depth-6 card-panel teal">
        <h1>Hi</h1><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```